# Different R structures on a complex variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I was reading Springer's *Linear Algebraic Groups* and I came across this problem 1.3.9 on page 6.

> Let $k = \mathbb{C}$, $\;F = \mathbb{R}$, $\;k[X] = k[T,U]/(T^2 + U^2 -1)$, and let $a,b$ be the images of $T,U$ in $k[X]$.
>
> Show that $F[a,b]$ and $F[ia,ib]$ define two different $F$ structures on $X$.

I can show that they are both $F$-structures. However, I do not see how they are different or what it even means for $F$-structures to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the intuition. $F[a, b]$ corresponds geometrically to the circle $x^2+y^2-1=0$ over $\mathbb{R}$. But $F[ia, ib]$ corresponds to $-x^2-y^2-1=0$, i.e. $x^2+y^2=-1$ over $\mathbb{R}$. This does not have any solutions over $\mathbb{R}$, but the circle has many solutions (a circle worth of solutions).

In short, $F[a, b]$ and $F[ia, ib]$ defines two different $F$-structures on $X$ because the $F$-points of the first one is non-empty (namely, the circle in $\mathbb{R}$), while the second one has no $F$-point. I guess the key here is that two same $F$-structures should certainly have same number of $F$-points. Okay, hopefully someone will give a more complete answer!

Comment: Thanks! This indeed looks good. But what does it mean for $F-$structures to be different?

Comment: No problem. The notion of the $F$-structure is explained at the top of page 6 in Springer's book. Namely, an $F$-structure on $k[X]$ is a finitely generated $F$-algebra $A_0$ (which is a subalgebra of $A$) such that the homomorphism induced by the multiplication $k\otimes_{F_0} A_0 \to k[X]$ is an isomorphism. Then $A_0$ is usually denoted $F[X]$. So what does it mean for two $F$-structures $A_0$ and $A'_0$ to be isomorphic? Well, the only sensible definition would be to require that two algebras $A_0$ and $A'_0$ are isomorphic as $F$-algebras, which is compatible with multiplication above.

Comment: In particular, if two $F$-structures are isomorphic, they surely have the same number of $F$-rational points, because $F$-rational points can be identified with the homomorphisms $F[X]\to F$. Thus, once you can show that two $F$-structures have different number of $F$-rational points, the two structures are different (i.e. not isomorphic)